# Response Redirect - Open Link in New Window

Tags: c#, asp.net

First, I've taken the time to review this question which seems to be the most similar, however, the solution that seems to have been selected will not work in my scenario.Not to mention I worry about some of the comments claiming it to be brittle or an inadequate solution.

[Response.Redirect to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/asp-net-response-redirect-to-new-window)

-We have an XML document which basically contains all of the information for a Side menu.

-We have numerous URLS which are stored in a constants class.

-One of the elements in a string of XML (well call it label) is used to determine if the menu item is created as a LinkButton or a Label.

-Links use a custom user control that is used standard for all links across the application (why suggestion on similar thread doesn't work - I don't want all links to open in a new window - just one)

-One of the elements in a string of XML (well call it function) is used in a Switch statement to generate our links using Response Redirect.

It may look something like this.

```
    switch (function)
    {
      case goto 1:
        string url;
        if (user_group == 1)
        {
            url = Constants.CONSTANT1
        }
        else
        {
            url = Constants.CONSTANT2
        }
        Response.Redirect(url)
      case goto 2:
        ......
      default:
        ......
        break;
}
```

Given this scenario, I'm trying to find the best way to quickly open a New Window, when a specific case in this switch statement is met. Can it be done with Response Redirect (this seems to be arguable  - people say no it can't, yet other people say they have made it work)? If not, what alternative can work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are lost. THe response redirect results in a redirect being sent to the browser - in the CURRENT window.

THe only way to open something in a new window would be to emit a html page that then opens the new URL in another window (which is a property on the anchor), or that emits javascript doing that.

Sadly, this has to be decided PRIOR to calling your method - once your method is called, the HTTP request is on the way. WHoever designed that ignored willfully the request/response mechanism that is the basic of browsers.

Those who say they got it work, did not do so on the server side. THe server has NO authority to redirect a request to a new browser window - that has to originate in the browser to start with before the request is made. If for nothing else, then for security reasons.

Comment: I appreciate this explanation. Fortunately, I was able to find an alternatate method when we wire up the linkbutton control. if (function == goto_1) { lnkbtn.Attributes["onclick"] = "window.open('url')" }