# How to open ASP page in a new tab/window?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I know that the HTML anchor tag  has an attribute called **target**, which will open a new page in a new window/tab if we set `target='_blank'`. It should work well with static HTML pages.

However, when we submitting a form by clicking the submit button on an **ASP** page, I find that the result page normally will be loaded into the same tab/window.

So my question is: are we able to load page into a new tab/window when user clicks submit button?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Looks like `<form target='blank'>` is the answer although its said to be deprecated according to w3schools website. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like a link:

```
<form target='_blank'>
```

No need to do anything on the ASP side of things. Of course, as with all pop-ups, this is subject to browser settings.

Comment: yeah I just found that out on w3schools [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp], but it says the attribute target is deprecated.

Comment: W3Schools seems to be in error. The target attribute in general is theoretically available only with a Loose or Transitional doctype, but in practice, I believe that every browser will support it even if you declare Strict.

Comment: Ignore w3Schools, w3c spec for forms includes the target attribute as part of html5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html

Answer (score 4):

Form's target shold work.

```
<form target="_blank" ...></form>
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window/179015#179015) (have you searched?)

Comment: haha, indeed gentlemen. Will be using search more next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out..

[Response.Redirect to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/asp-net-response-redirect-to-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods for redirecting the page to new tab in **asp**

> 1) Make an onclientclick event of Button and on code behind of Button
>   Click write the following code:-

```
button.OnClientClick = "aspnetForm.target='_blank'"; Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx");
```

> 2)You can also use javascript

```
 button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('yourpage.aspx');return false;");
```

Both the method will redirect your page to new tab on clicking the button.