# open an external link in a new tab from within an asp.net project

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am planning to open an external link ("www.google.com") in a "new tab of the same window" from within my asp.net project on button click. Is there a way to do it. (The links come from the database and looks like I cant do it in markup side).

Currently I tried , response.redirect & window.open but both don't seem to work.

```
Response.Redirect
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Response.Redirect("www.google.com");
        }
```

Window.Open

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {   
string x = "www.google.com";

       string s = "window.open('" + x + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
  }
```

The error I get in both cases is : 404 page not found..

[image]

Comment: Did you notice the error message... the 'Requested URL' shows the reason for the issue. Is it okay to use jquery in your application? In my project, I am using a jquery based solution to achieve similar functionality.

Comment: Yes ! I can use jquery .. Please let me know how I can achieve it in jquery. The error was because I should use "http://www.google.com" instead of "www.google.com". Also, I need to open the new url in a new tab. Response.redirect opens the new url in the same window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the URL being requested:

```
http://localhost/www.google.com
```

If you're directing the user to another site, you have to fully-qualify the URL:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

or:

```
string x = "http://www.google.com";
```

Otherwise the browser thinks it's looking for a resource called "www.google.com" on the current site.

Comment: Thanks that works partially, but as I mentioned in my question I want to open the new url  as a "new tab of the same window". How can I do that ? The above solution opens the url as a new window.

Comment: @CodeNinja: The JavaScript `window.open()` should do exactly that.  Is that not working in your browser?

Comment: The window.open() is opening in a new window instead of a new tab on the same window. I am using internet explorer. The code is below.             string x = "https://www.google.com";

            string s = "window.open('" + x + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);

Comment: @CodeNinja: It's up to the browser how to open the new window object, whether it's a tab or a separate window.  The code can't control that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is send a chunk of html down the response that has a link with your url as an href, target="_blank" and a chunk of javascript onload of the form that fakes a click. If this doesn't work then use a window.open("www.google.com");

```
response.write("<script>");
response.write("window.open('www.google.com','_blank')");
response.write("</script>");
```

Full description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994285/how-do-i-use-target-blank-on-a-response-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

You have  to specify the full URL,  so use

```
 Response.Redirect("Http://www.google.com");
```

Goodluck.

Comment: Hey Slashy ! Thanks ! But the above solution opens the url "www.google.com" in the same window. As I mentioned in my question, I would like to open the new link "as a new tab in the same window". How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = "https://www.google.com";

        string s = "window.open('" + x + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

According to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript), you can't open it in new window in this way.

if you really want it in a new Window then use [HTML Links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) with `target="_blank"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks that works partially, but as I mentioned in my question I want to open the new url  as a "new tab of the same window". How can I do that ? The above solution opens the url as a new window.

Answer (score 0):

The URL www.google.com is interpreted as local path, try

```
http://www.google.com
```

instead.

Using _new as window name opens a new window or tab:

```
window.open("...", "_new")
```