# URL relative to server

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an ASP.NET button in my application, which I want to open another website on my server in a new window. Currently I do a Response.Redirect in my server side on click event (to "..\OtherWebsite") which works. But as it needs to be in a new window I need to do it in JavaScript.

Would '..\OtherWebsite' path work in the window.open JavaScript command? If not, what .NET methods/properties can I use to get the full path?

I can't hard code the website URL as some users will be accessing through a LAN (server name\application) and some through the website (www.website.com/application)

Comment: A redirect path is relative to where the page is hosted, not where the client is.

Comment: I'm unable to test at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.location.href` to get the currect url of the page, next form your new url relative to that and then pass it to `window.open()` method.

Here is the definition of [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by executing the javascript from the codebehind.

```
public void OpenNewWindow(string url)
{

   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", url));
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1001747.aspx/1

First result from searching for "open new window from codebehind c# .net"

Then just pass the relative url like so.

```
String url = "~/page.aspx";
url = Page.ResolveClientUrl(url);
OpenNewWindow(url);
```

also a reference here: [Response.Redirect to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/asp-net-response-redirect-to-new-window)

Hope this helps.