# How to open a url in new tab when user click menu item?

Tags: asp.net, menu, response.redirect

Currently, when the menu item is clicked on the web page in the event handler the new url is assigned to Response.Redirect and so it is opening in the same window. I want to be able to open the new url in a new tab keeping the main webpage open. I tried giving target="_blank" to the menu item and it doenst help . Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Check this :
[ASP.NET Response.Redirect to new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/asp-net-response-redirect-to-new-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume need to do a POST so you can calculate the new URL based on some posted data?

If that's the case, you could set target="_new" on the form tag - targets work for POSTs as well as GETs.

Or you could return the new URL to the client and then do a window.open when the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach a client side handler instead of a server side one.

Formally - instead of the "OnClick" attach "onmenuitemclick" to a javascript expression which opens new window - "window.open( ... )".

Comment: sepecifying 

        Navigateurl="newurl" Target="_new"

serves the purpose, but the new url is only updated dynamically on servere side. So am trying to find a way where I can set the navigate url property on serverside.