# Web form non-responsive after download

Tags: asp.net, browser, download

I'm working in ASP.NET (2.0) and we have a page where a user is able to select and download a series of files as a zip.  I got this to work without undo difficulty by using the DotNetZip library (which is probably not relevant to the problem, but included for completeness.)

After the user checks which files they want to download, the page does a postback, and in the button click event handler, I use the following code:

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = false; // false = stream immediately
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=FileRequest.zip");

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddFile(MapPath("/datafiles/fileToZip.pdf"), "");
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    }
    Response.Close();
```

And this all seems to work great.  The user clicks the button, a download window pops up, the user downloads the zip.  All is good...

...until they decide they want to do something else on the page.  The buttons in the form are no longer responsive.  For instance, if I click the download button again, it does nothing.  If I reload the page, I can repeat this behavior...it works once, then does nothing.

I'm not understanding why the browser doesn't send the new request.  It's not "spinning" or otherwise acting busy.  I thought that this might be a browser issue, but I've repeated it in both IE and Firefox, so it seems likely that it's something I'm not understanding.  Strangely, it's only form submission elements that seem to be non-responsive.  Javascript still works, and so do regular links.

So why is this happening, and how do I get around it?

Comment: Seem's that somehow viewstate postback is broken on page. Because all button events in webforms are based on JS. Try to return the zip content in separate window, don't overwrite response on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely down to you returning;

```
   Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
```

Once this has been sent (along with the actual content), the browser would assume it has nothing left to do (I believe).

You probably should create a new window specifically for downloading the files by saving the file selection in a session parameter (or equivalent) and opening a popup window that has your download code in.

This will leave the parent page in a suitable state.

Answer (score 0):

Content-disposition header [seems to be a discouraged solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header). But the same effect of ASP.NET forms not being responsive occurs if you use standard *Redirect* to a zip file.

I solved very similar problem (returning *.csv files by the server for download) using Tančev Saša's code in "[Response.Redirect to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/response-redirect-to-new-window)" Q&A and it works great. Perhaps it might produce some popup warnings in some browsers, but I think this is how it's often done in download sites.