# Response.Redirect with "rel="external" parameter like a href"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, vb.net, jquery-mobile

I use asp.net (vb.net) and i want to redirect user at button click event.

```
Response.Redirect("somepage.aspx", False)
```

it was worked. but when i use this method, the menu (which in somepage.aspx) doesn't work. because it was want to "external" parameters like :

```
<a href="somepage.aspx" rel="external">
```

if i call somepage.aspx with above html code,my menu is work .
(i used jscript also)

so i want to run response.redirect with parameters like "a href"; for example;

```
 Response.Redirect("somepage.aspx", False,"rel=external")
```

how can i do this in serverside code?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firat,

There is no out of the box available for Response.Redirect, but you can see below and use one that fit your needs:

[Response.Redirect into a new window](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/317410/Response-Redirect-into-a-new-window)
[Response.Redirect to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/response-redirect-to-new-window)