# How to set Target = _blank

Tags: html, query-string, response.redirect

I want to set `target =_blank` to the following code, so that the *Test.aspx* page open in new window.

```
 Response.Redirect("Test.aspx?D1=" + TextBox1.Text + "&D2=" + TextBox2.Text);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please see ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/response-redirect-to-new-window

Answer (score 5):

try to add this to your object:

`OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"`

or put it in ASP.NET like here:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" 
                OnClick="myButton_Click" 
                OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/>
```

like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/response-redirect-to-new-window)

The other part you need to add is to fix the form's target otherwise every link will open in a new window. To do so add the following in the header of your POPUP window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fixform() {
        if (opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").target != "_blank") return;
        opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").target = "";
        opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").action = opener.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

and then add:

```
<body onload="fixform()">
```

Comment: where to put? its not working properly if I set it on Page_Load

Comment: yes I red that one. but the problem is when I put OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';", only one button then it works for every button on the master page. why?