# ASP.NET MVC redirect - how to open in new window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have the following template which redirects the user which works fine, how can I get it so it opens up in a new window?

```
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";

    var links = Model.Value<IEnumerable<Link>>("linkTarget");

    if (links != null && links.Any())
    {
        var prettyLink = links.FirstOrDefault();
        Context.Response.Redirect(prettyLink.Url,true);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/response-redirect-to-new-window). This might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try following codes;

```
response.write("<script>");response.write("window.open('index.html','_blank')");response.write("</script>");
```

Comment: Thanks, which part of my code would I replace with the above?